# Hero banner doesn't stay dismissed

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The hero banner on Jobs continues to show itself, even after clicking the dismiss link. I know what Jobs is and actively use it to see what positions are available. I don't need a reminder of what it is every time I go to Jobs.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open Firefox and visit Stack Overflow
2. Click on the Jobs tab on the top bar
3. [Click the dismiss link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARYp8.png)
4. At some point close Firefox

Step 4 appears to be the important step. If I leave the browser open, the hero banner doesn't return. However, if I close the browser and then revisit Jobs when it's reopened, the banner has returned.

Comment: Do you have Firefox configured to clear cookies on exit?

Comment: I do not clear anything on exit, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, yeh, it was marked as a session cookie when the intent was that it should be dismissed a little bit more forever. I've fixed the relevant code and pushed to production. Thanks the report!